# What are the differences in performance and carbon footprint between HTML5 and XHTML1.0 in 2022?

Tags: html, performance, xhtml

I have a very simple website, but somehow dated, that works flawlessly here : [lyaudet.eu/laurent](https:/lyaudet.eu/laurent/).
There is no server side rendering, only static XHTML pages and a CSS file.
I already know that static files are very performant and have a low carbon footprint, so please no answer like "It does not matter, just take the latest technology.".
I want to know how much difference there is in the latency and navigator energy consumption between HTML5 files and XHTML files, since the syntax of XML is simpler than the syntax of SGML.
I assume that both static HTML5 and XHTML files are valid without error or warning here: [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/).
Answers like :

- "For 10KiB webfiles, XHTML latency is between x1 and y1 and carbon footprint is between z1 and t1, whilst HTML5 latency is between x2 and y2 and carbon footprint is between z2 and t2",
- or even like "For 15KiB webfiles, XHTML latency follows approximately a normal distribution like..."

I tried to look at speed tests and online carbon footprint calculators. But I was wondering if public or corporate researchers studied this question (or a broader one) with some kind of "reference webpages". I checked also on the Internet including this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195840/what-are-the-main-differences-between-xhtml-and-html)

Comment: XHTML1.0 is a more than 20 years old version of XHTML, sure you want to compare these 2 markup languages in 2022?

Comment: I'm ok with an answer for XHTML1.1 instead of XHTML1.0 ;) There is no more recent XHTML that passed the draft status as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you are right.

Comment: On the contrary, XHTML lives on in HTML5. It's called the XML syntax of HTML5 and follows exactly the same rules - XML compliant and must be served with a content type of `application/xhtml+xml`, just as XHTML 1.1 must be. For the purposes of performance and carbon footprint, it would be much easier to to a like for like comparison with it.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It is here : https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/the-xhtml-syntax.html I also accept any answer comparing the two syntaxes of HTML5.